# Syntax of GROUP BY ROLLUP in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am reading a book about mysql and in one of the examples the following code is shown, which just does not work when I try it in mysql

```
SELECT item_description, material, weight, sum(quantity)
FROM Products
GROUP BY ROLLUP(item_description, material, weight)
```

Is this a right syntax ?

Also I find out that doing

```
SELECT item_description, material, weight, sum(quantity)
FROM Products
GROUP BY item_description, material, weight WITH ROLLUP;
```

works and I was wondering if the first code is correct and if it is doing
the same thing as the second code.

Comment: SQL http://www.careerride.com/SQL-server-CUBE-ROLLUP.aspx AND  MYSQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html syntax different for ROLLUP

Comment: Great, so the material is about MYSQL but it uses SQL syntax :)

Thanks for pointing that out by the way.

Comment: can i put it in anwer @Legatus Gat